# Getting string value for specific integer value in enum c#

Tags: c#, enums

Ok this question might be really simple and stupid to answer but I'm loss right now.

I have an enum declared as it follows:

```
public enum legende : int
{
    NONE = 0, 
    Création = 1, 
    Reprise = 2 , 
    Pause = 3, 
    Problème_instruction = 4,
    Fix_manquant = 5,
    Outil_non_adéquat = 6,
    Laser = 7,
    Pièces_manquantes = 8,
    Attente_qualité = 9,
    Dérogation = 10,
    Séquencement = 11,
    Charge_Planif_Insuff = 12,
    TERA = 13,
    Changement_d_OF = 14,
    OFF_Fin_shift = 1014,
    Inaccessible = 1015
};
```

and I'm trying to access a specific value using his integer value(this is where I can't quite get it to work) :

```
public legende legend = new legende();
item.Action = Enum.Parse(legend, "2"); //random example of what I'm trying to do
```

Comment: item.Action being a string type

Comment: Are you asking for `item.Action = (legende)2;`?

Comment: What do you mean by `index`?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "index", what specifically did you expect `item.Action` to become?

Comment: I mean I'm trying to get TERA value if I only tell him value 13

Comment: If you're trying to get the `legende` value that corresponds to the `int` value of 2, which would be `Reprise`, you can do: `item.Action = (legende)2`, if you have a string containing a number you can parse it first: `item.Action = (legende)int.Parse(s)`

Comment: @maccettura That's what I was looking for too, derp.

Comment: index being 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ...

Comment: Index usually means "the 4th element" and since your numbers end with 1014 and 1015 it isn't *clear* what you want to happen. What if you ask for the value corresponding to 15, should that work? Give you `OFF_Fin_shift` or just not be entirely OK.

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I am wrong, but "index" probably isn't the word OP is looking for.  Enums are not a "collection", OP wants to cast to an enum from a backing value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast an integer to the enum type:

```
//  leg will be legende.Reprise
legend leg = (legende)2;
```

If I correctly understand you that Action is a string, you can then just call `ToString()` on the enum value; this will return `"Reprise"`:

```
item.Action = leg.ToString();
```

or

```
item.Action = ((legende)2).ToString();
```

Or as you ended up doing:

```
item.Action = Convert.ToString((legende)2);
```

If `legende` has two or more members that share the integer value `2`, this will give you the first one.

"Index" isn't the correct term; "integer value" would be better.

Comment: Ok this is what I was trying to do!! I edited question to change the "index" word thanks

Comment: @EdPlunkett Damn you beat me to my comment about "index"

Comment: @maccettura Well, I had to get *one* thing right today.

Comment: thanks for your edit but I simply did: Convert.ToString((legende)2)

Comment: @J.Lavoie That works too. Added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use `Enum.Parse`,

```
item.Action = (legende)Enum.Parse(typeof(legende), "2");
```

Comment: I did not know that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, nice way of doing it! +1